# Making Geometries clickable Hyperlinks in Three.js (WebGl Renderer)

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

So I've been trying to make a spherical 360 panorama using three.js which implements clickable objects, which at the moment I would like to make hyperlinks.I've read many of the previous examples of raycasting and such, but have had no luck in getting the object to actually redirect me to the site. If someone could tell me where I'm going wrong in the code I'd greatly appreciate it.

I have a feeling the orbiting/panning function under "onDocumentMouseDown" is interfering with the raycasting? I'm still new to this and figuring it out.

```
<div id="container"></div>
    <script src="three.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var container, stats;
        var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
        var objects = [], plane;

        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(),
        offset = new THREE.Vector3();

        var fov = 70,
        texture_placeholder,
        isUserInteracting = false,
        onMouseDownMouseX = 0, onMouseDownMouseY = 0,
        lon = 0, onMouseDownLon = 0,
        lat = 0, onMouseDownLat = 0,
        phi = 0, theta = 0;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {
            var container, mesh1, sphere1, cube1;

            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100 );
            camera.target = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500, 60, 40 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'spherical_map_small.jpg' ), transparent: true} ) );
            mesh1.scale.x = -1;
            scene.add( mesh1 );

            meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff});

            var sphere1 = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 2.5,20,20 ), meshMaterial );
            sphere1.position.set( 50, 10, 0 );
            scene.add( sphere1 );

            sphere1.userData = { URL:"http://www.google.com"};

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'DOMMouseScroll', onDocumentMouseWheel, false);

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        }

        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }

        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            isUserInteracting = true;

            onPointerDownPointerX = event.clientX;
            onPointerDownPointerY = event.clientY;

            onPointerDownLon = lon;
            onPointerDownLat = lat;

            raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( sphere1 );

            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                controls.enabled = true;

                SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].sphere1;

                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( sphere1 );
                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                    window.open(intersects[0].object.userData.URL);
                }
            }   
        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
            if ( isUserInteracting ) {
                lon = ( onPointerDownPointerX - event.clientX ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLon;
                lat = ( event.clientY - onPointerDownPointerY ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLat;
            }
        }

        function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {
            isUserInteracting = false;
        }

        function onDocumentMouseWheel( event ) {
            isUserInteracting = false;
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }

        function render() {
            lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
            phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
            theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );

            camera.target.x = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
            camera.target.y = 500 * Math.cos( phi );
            camera.target.z = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );

            camera.lookAt( camera.target );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I notice that you create `var mouse = new THREE.Vector2()`, then you don't set its values at any point in the supplied code. Then in  `onDocumentMouseDown()` you cast a ray into the scene with undefined mouse coordinates `raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );` As var `mouse` has not been set it is very likely that that is the reason you are not getting the navigation to start.

What you need to do is get the normalised screen coordiantes of the mouse and pass that into the `raycaster.setFromCamera` I can not quite remenber if the screen is one or two units but something like

```
mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth);  // normalise the mouse screen pos
mouse.y = (event.clientY / window.innerHeight); // same

mouse.x *= 2; // 0 is the center. -1 is left and 1 is right
mouse.y -= 1;  // center 

mouse.y *= -2; // Think this is upside down If it does not work try positive 2
mouse.y += 1;  // center
```

if it does not work try switching mouse.y the otherway around;

```
mouse.y *= 2; //  remove the -2 and put in 2
mouse.y -= 1;  // remove the += and put in -=
```

What I find very handy when messing about in 3D is to have a spare debug object in the scene. Something simple like a box or sphere. Use it to show a point on the raycaster's ray.

Something like

```
// creat a box
var box... blah blah box creation code/
boxP = new vector3(); // position of debug object
// position it halfway in the raycasters range
boxP.x = camera.x + rayCaster.ray.x* ((rayCaster.near+rayCaster.far)/2);
boxP.y = camera.y + rayCaster.ray.y* ((rayCaster.near+rayCaster.far)/2);
boxP.z = camera.z + rayCaster.ray.z* ((rayCaster.near+rayCaster.far)/2);
box.position.set(boxP.x,boxP.y,boxP.z);
```

Now with luck you should see where you clicks are going.

Also, I am not sure but if you are looking at the sphere from the inside you may have to set the material to doubleSided (I can't see it in your code) as the raycaster ignores faces with normals pointing away. Or try reversing the direction of each polygon.

That's about all I can suggest at the moment. Hope you find the problem.